# I cant navigate to from login screen to home in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I am developing Android app using Jetpack compose when I try to navigate from ReaderLoginScreen to Home screen it is not navigate to home screen

below my code in ReaderLoginScreen.kt

```
viewModel.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password){
                    navController.navigate(ReaderScreens.ReaderHomeScreen.name)
                }
```

where I am trying to navigate from ReaderLoginScreen to ReaderHomeScreen

below is my Navigation setup  ReaderNavigation.kt

```
@Composable
fun  ReaderNavigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = ReaderScreens.SplashScreen.name){
       composable(ReaderScreens.SplashScreen.name){
           ReaderSplashScreen(navController = navController)
       }
        composable(ReaderScreens.LoginScreen.name){
            ReaderLoginScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(ReaderScreens.ReaderHomeScreen.name){
            Home(navController = navController)
        }
    }
}
```

below my ReaderHomeScreen.kt

```
 import androidx.compose.material.Text
    import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
    import androidx.navigation.NavController
    
    @Composable
    fun Home(navController: NavController) {
        Text(text = "I am home")
    
    }
```

below my LoginScreenViewModel.kt

```
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class LoginScreenViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // val loadingState = MutableStateFlow(LoadingState.IDLE)
    private val auth: FirebaseAuth = Firebase.auth
    private val _loading = MutableLiveData(false)
    val loading: LiveData<Boolean> = _loading

    fun signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String, home:() -> Unit) = viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                       // Log.d("FB", "signInWithEmailAndPassword${task.result}")
                        home
                        // Login
                    } else {
                        Log.d("FB", "signInWithEmailAndPassword${task.result}")

                    }
                }

        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Log.d("FB", "signInWithEmailAndPassword${ex.message}")
        }
    }

    fun createUserWithEmailAndPassword() {

    }


}
```

I want to know where I am making mistake

Comment: In your ViewModel you're not calling `home` function. You need to invoke it: `home()`

Comment: thank you so much I fixed issue I was stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by calling  function by following way

```
viewModel.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password, home = {})
                    navController.navigate(ReaderScreens.ReaderHomeScreen.name)

            }
```